# How to optimise my partial view loading time? (C#, MVC, jQuery)

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, model-view-controller, asp.net-core-mvc

For this feature, I want the respective tour package details (partial view.cshtml) to load in the main view (view.cshtml) as I select the different options. The problem I am facing now is that, the partial view content loads way too slowly.

For example,
Tour A package detail: New Zealand Tour (16 Day)
Tour B pacakage detail: New Zealand Tour (14 Day)

if i click onto card A, it takes a long time for New Zealand Tour (16 Day) to appear
if i click onto card B, New Zealand Tour (16 Day) will still be there, only after a long time of waiting, then it will switch to New Zealand Tour (14 Day)

sorry i tried to attach the gif demo but it doesn't allow me to upload

here are my codes:

**View.cshtml**

```
@using StiWebsite.Models;
@using System.Security.Policy
@model dynamic

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Experiential";
}
<div class="row addCss3" style="padding: 0 1rem" id="paddingRow">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
        <div class="row filterPart">
            <div class="dropdown filter imm" id="ddlFilter" style="z-index: 2">
                <select id="studyTourFilter" class="form-control selectpicker">
                    <option class="worldSelect" value="" data-content="<img id='studyTourFilterIcon' class='img-responsive icon' src='/assets/img/immigration/flag/world.png'></img> Select Country">Select Country</option>
                    @foreach (Country country in Model.countryL)
                    {
                        @if (country.CountryID == "AUEXP" || country.CountryID == "CAEXP" || country.CountryID == "ITEXP"
                       || country.CountryID == "NZEXP" || country.CountryID == "SGEXP" || country.CountryID == "SPEXP")
                        {
                            <option id="studyTourOption" value="@Url.Content(country.CountryID)" data-content="<img id='studyTourFilterIcon' class='img-responsive icon' src='@Url.Content(country.CountryImg)'></img> @Url.Content(country.CountryName)">@country.CountryName</option>
                        }
                    }
                </select>
                @foreach (Country country in Model.countryL)
                {
                    @if (country.CountryID == "AUEXP" || country.CountryID == "ITEXP" || country.CountryID == "NZEXP" || country.CountryID == "SGEXP" || country.CountryID == "SPEXP")
                    {
                        <div id="tourSelect-@Url.Content(country.CountryID)" class="tourSelect hidden">
                            <div class="row expcaurosel">
                                <p id="cauroTitle" class="card-title">Our Packages</p>
                                @foreach (StudyTour tour in Model.studyTourL)
                                {
                                    @if (tour.CountryID == country.CountryID)
                                    {
                                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 expCard">
                                            <button id="cauroLinkBtn" type="button" href="@Url.Action("tourPackage", "Experiential", new {id = tour.StudyTourID})" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#staticBackdrop">
                                                @Html.Raw(tour.StudyTourContent)
                                            </button>
                                        </div>
                                    }
                                }
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    }
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal fade" id="staticBackdrop" data-backdrop="static" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="staticBackdropLabel"></h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true"><img class="img-responsive" src="/assets/img/experiential/icon/7.png"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

                **PARTIAL VIEW APPEAR HERE**
                <div id="partialView"></div>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts {
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/jscript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("div>button").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#partialView").load($(this).attr("href"));
        });
    });
</script>
}
```

**Partial View cshtml**

```
@using StiWebsite.Models;
@using System.Security.Policy
@model StudyTourImgPackage;

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Tour Package Details";
}

<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
    <div class="row title" id="progTitle" style="display: block;">
        <div id="packageProgram" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12" style="background-color: #fafafa; overflow: hidden">

            @Html.Raw(Model.PackageContent)

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using StiWebsite.Data;
using StiWebsite.Models;
using System.Dynamic;

namespace StiWebsite.Controllers
{
    public class ExperientialController : Controller
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext _db;
        public ExperientialController(ApplicationDbContext db)
        {
            _db = db;
        }

        [Route("experiential")]
        public IActionResult Experiential()
        {
            dynamic expModel = new ExpandoObject();
            expModel.expL = getExperientialContent();
            expModel.studyTourL = getStudyTour();
            expModel.tourPackL = getTourPackage();
            expModel.countryL = getCountry();
            expModel.studyImgPackL = getStudyTourImgPackages();
            return View(expModel);
        }

        //[Route("experiential")]
        public PartialViewResult tourPackage(string? id)
        {
            IEnumerable<StudyTourImgPackage> tourDb = getStudyTourImgPackages();
            var detail = tourDb.First(x => x.StudyTourID == id);
            return PartialView("tourPackage", detail);
        }
        public List<StudyTourImgPackage> getStudyTourImgPackages()
        {
            var expTourList = (from x in _db.TourPackage
                               select new StudyTourImgPackage
                               {
                                   PackageID = x.PackageID,
                                   PackageTitle = x.PackageTitle,
                                   PackageContent = x.PackageContent,
                                   PackageIcon = x.PackageIcon,
                                   PackageIconAltText = x.PackageIconAltText,
                                   StudyTourID = x.StudyTourID,
                                   StudyTourTitle = x.StudyTour.StudyTourTitle,
                                   StudyTourContent = x.StudyTour.StudyTourContent,
                                   StudyTourImg = x.StudyTour.StudyTourImg,
                                   StudyTourImgAltText = x.StudyTour.StudyTourImgAltText,
                                   CountryID = x.StudyTour.CountryID,
                                   CountryName = x.StudyTour.Country.CountryName

                               }).ToList();
            return expTourList;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add some `Stopwatche` to check which code path takes long time to execute and needs to be optimized?

Comment: For your use `@Html.Raw()`, did the content in it contains large html elements? I think it will spend much time converting string to html.